# Make content slide over h1 parallax. z-index won't apply

Tags: javascript, html, css, z-index, parallax

I'm trying to make the h1 tag, "Portfolio" disappear underneath the next section (just a bunch of purple) as the user scrolls down.

I tried making the h1 text have a z-index of -1, but that makes the text disappear underneath the background image.

If I set the z-index higher for the content that should slide over top of the text, the h1 "Portfolio" is still on top. How can I create the parallax effect on the text "Portfolio"?  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QNaoyO

Bonus points if you can have the same effect if the background is NOT an image, but a color. I currently just have a picture of a color as the background.

HTML

```
<div id="portfolio"><h1 id="portfolioTitle">Portfolio</h1></div>

<section class="mainContent" style="height: 600px; background-color: purple;"></div>
```

CSS
    #portfolioTitle {
      text-align: center;
      width: 75%;
      position: fixed;
      left: 50%;
      margin-left: -37.5%;
      /*z-index: -1*//*makes it disappear*/
    }

```
.mainContent {
  z-index: 10;
}

#portfolio {
  /*background-color: #27f5eb;*/
  /*background-color: #DD67F5;*/
  background-image: url(https://www.startupinacar.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/blackjackPic.png);
  height: 300px;
  /*position: fixed;*/
  background-attachment: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Background colors should work just the same as images.

```css
#portfolio {
  height: 300px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #27f5eb;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.mainContent {
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  height: 1000px; 
  background: purple;
  margin-top: 300px;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

body {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
```

```html
<div id="portfolio">
    <h1>Portfolio</h1>
</div>

<section class="mainContent">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize there was a difference with how background-attachment: fixed and position: fixed, works. One fixed the problem, the other did not. oh.. It might have been the relative positioning of the mainContent...

Answer (score 2):

```
.mainContent {
  position:relative;  /* you're missing a position */
  z-index: 10;        /* in order for z-index to apply */
}
```

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/lafuvo/1/edit?html,css,output)***

Comment: My answer would've been just about the same except I used a `position: absolute;` and added a `width: 100%` to .mainContent. See here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VayRPL